# Batch file won't run as administrator unless via cmd prompt

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch, administrator

I'm trying to write a batch file that will turn Apache off and copy some files. This is all I have in the script at the moment:

```
"C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe" -k stop
```

If I either run the batch file normally, or right click and select "run as administrator" the console window flashes up and I can briefly see the message "Access denied".

If I instead open a cmd prompt as administrator, and then run the batch file through that, it works perfectly. Please help, I need to do this task on a daily basis and want it to be as quick as a double click

I use Windows 7 Pro btw.

Comment: Firstly two things to try/do... Add Pause to the next line of the batch file so you can see what is happening after the command runs. Secondly can you load CMD as administrator and run the command as it is without the batch file simply open CMD as admin and type out the same command.. Let me know how you get on..

Comment: This sounds like you have changed the association of the .bat extension or you have malware/virus on your machine. Can you check why the default value is of .BAT under the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT?  I accidentally changed mine once so that I was always editing if I double clicked a batch file and hand to manually run via command prompt till I fixed my registry.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment above, if you have messed with your registry association, backup your registry, then save the following as a .reg and apply to reset to W7 defaults for .BAT:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bat]
@="batfile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bat\PersistentHandler]
@="{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile]
@="Windows Batch File"
"EditFlags"=hex:30,04,00,00
"FriendlyTypeName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,\
  00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,\
  32,00,5c,00,61,00,63,00,70,00,70,00,61,00,67,00,65,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,\
  00,2c,00,2d,00,36,00,30,00,30,00,32,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\DefaultIcon]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,69,00,6d,00,\
  61,00,67,00,65,00,72,00,65,00,73,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,36,\
  00,38,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\edit]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\edit\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,4e,00,4f,00,\
  54,00,45,00,50,00,41,00,44,00,2e,00,45,00,58,00,45,00,20,00,25,00,31,00,00,\
  00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open]
"EditFlags"=hex:00,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command]
@="\"%1\" %*"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\print]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\print\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,4e,00,4f,00,\
  54,00,45,00,50,00,41,00,44,00,2e,00,45,00,58,00,45,00,20,00,2f,00,70,00,20,\
  00,25,00,31,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\runas]
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\runas\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,63,00,6d,00,\
  64,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,2f,00,43,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,\
  00,20,00,25,00,2a,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\runasuser]
@="@shell32.dll,-50944"
"Extended"=""
"SuppressionPolicyEx"="{F211AA05-D4DF-4370-A2A0-9F19C09756A7}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\runasuser\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{ea72d00e-4960-42fa-ba92-7792a7944c1d}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\ShellEx]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers]
@="Compatibility"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\Compatibility]
@="{1d27f844-3a1f-4410-85ac-14651078412d}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\ShellEx\DropHandler]
@="{86C86720-42A0-1069-A2E8-08002B30309D}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\ShellEx\PropertySheetHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\ShellEx\PropertySheetHandlers\PifProps]
@="{86F19A00-42A0-1069-A2E9-08002B30309D}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\ShellEx\PropertySheetHandlers\ShimLayer Property Page]
@="{513D916F-2A8E-4F51-AEAB-0CBC76FB1AF8}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\ShellEx\{8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f}]
@="{1531d583-8375-4d3f-b5fb-d23bbd169f22}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It asks for UAC prompt and runs the command as administrator.

```
:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
:--------------------------------------
:: ADD COMMANDS TO BE RUN AS ADMIN BELOW.

"C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe" -k stop
```

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: tried, but the code tags got messed up. When i put the script content in code tags, not entire content looked as desired..

Comment: Fixed that for you. You should learn how to use [markup](http://superuser.com/editing-help).

Comment: What you also need to do is add something telling us **where** you got this from. I've seen lots of variations of this batch file and I don't think you are the author. Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing)

Comment: Thank you. Definitely, im not its author. I have found that script long back and forgot the source. I use it regularly. It is close to this (but not same) http://stackoverflow.com/a/25238418 . The one i found exactly had till the line :: ADD COMMANDS TO BE RUN AS ADMIN BELOW. However its hard to find it now, since it had variations.

Comment: I don't believe that the problem is requesting elevation since even if he elevated the same problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
runas /noprofile /user:mymachine\administrator cmd
```

it's under (runas usage:examples) so it should work.